Router redirecting to nowhere on canActivate=false
I have a route with a CanActivate: [isEmployee].  I'm testing this for falseness.  It keeps redirecting to "" and then getting stuck.  Header/footer prints, blank body.  https://localhost/foo => https://localhost with no trailing slash.
I am using angular-oauth-oidc-client, but I think this is outside of that.  It's getting to the isEmployee and false is returned.
I'm trying to access /foo as a non-employee.  It should redirect to /startup which should redirect to /bar.
      {path: '', redirectTo: '/startup', pathMatch: 'full'}, //redirects to either foo or bar depending on if you're an employee or not
      {path: 'foo', component: FooComponent, canActivate: [AutoLoginPartialRoutesGuard, isEmployee]},
      {
        path: 'bar',
        component: BarComponent,
        canActivate: [AutoLoginPartialRoutesGuard] //does not require you to be an employee, just logged in
      },
      {path: 'startup', component: StartupComponent, canActivate: [AutoLoginPartialRoutesGuard]},
      {path: 'callback', component: CallbackComponent},
      {path: 'unauthorized', component: UnauthorizedComponent},

Here's my guard.
export const isEmployee = () => {
  const oidcSecurityService = inject(OidcSecurityService);
  const router = inject(Router);

  return oidcSecurityService.getUserData().pipe(
    take(1),
    map((userData) => {
      if (!userData) {
        return false;
      }
      return userData.UserType === 'Employee'; //this evaluates to false


please share the guard codes!

@NarenMurali what do you mean?

@NarenMurali, I see what you mean.  The isEmployee guard is returning false on purpose as I'm using a non-employee account. The other guard is from angular-oauth-oidc-client.  I've included it for your viewing, though.

return a Urltree if you want to redirect to some specific page

@MatthieuRiegler I want it to return to the default route.

What is a "default" route ?

@MatthieuRiegler https://angular.dev/guide/routing/common-router-tasks search for "default route".
